# Why do my JavaFX application's drag routines break in JavaFX 8?

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have some code that will allow me to drag an instance of a StackPane. The code works fine in JavaFX v2.2 but the StackPane stays in the default position and doesn't move in JavaFX v8.

Here is the code:

```
private void initDragRoutine(final Node source,
                             final boolean replaceSource,
                             final Node replaceWith,
                             final Pane replaceFrom)
{
    /*
     * add the draggable pane and create its text
     */
    source.setOnDragDetected(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent)
        {
            System.out.println("drag initialized");

            //update the content of the draggable instance with that of the fixed position source
            if (mouseEvent.getSource() instanceof StringPane)
                draggablePane.setOverlay(((StringPane) mouseEvent.getSource()).getOverlay());

            //update position
            Point2D localPoint = questionInfoNode.sceneToLocal(
                    new Point2D(mouseEvent.getSceneX(), mouseEvent.getSceneY()));
            draggablePane.relocate(
                    (int) (localPoint.getX() - draggablePane.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth() / 2),
                    (int) (localPoint.getY() - draggablePane.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight() / 2)
            );
            //add to scene
            styledRootNode.getChildren().add(draggablePane);

            draggablePane.startFullDrag();

            //replace source
            if (replaceSource && replaceFrom != null)
                for (int index = 0; index < replaceFrom.getChildren().size(); index++)
                    if (replaceFrom.getChildren().get(index) == source)
                        replaceFrom.getChildren().set(index, replaceWith);

            mouseEvent.consume();
        }
    });

    /*
     * update the position
     */
    source.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent)
        {
            System.out.println("dragged");

            //update position
            Point2D localPoint = questionInfoNode.sceneToLocal(
                    new Point2D(mouseEvent.getSceneX(), mouseEvent.getSceneY()));
            System.out.println("x" + mouseEvent.getSceneX() + "y" + mouseEvent.getSceneY());
            draggablePane.relocate(
                    (int) (localPoint.getX() - draggablePane.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth() / 2),
                    (int) (localPoint.getY() - draggablePane.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight() / 2)
            );
            //draggablePane.relocate(450, 1000);

            //source.setCursor(Cursor.NONE);
            mouseEvent.consume();
        }
    });

    /*
     * adjust cursor on entry
     */
    source.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
    {
        public void handle(MouseEvent e)
        {
            source.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
            e.consume();
        }
    });

    /*
     * adjust cursor on pressed
     */
    source.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
    {
        public void handle(MouseEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println("mouse pressed");

            source.setMouseTransparent(true);
            draggablePane.setMouseTransparent(true);
            source.setCursor(Cursor.CLOSED_HAND);

            e.consume();

            System.out.println("mouse pressed done");
        }
    });

    /*
     * adjust cursor on released
     */
    source.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
    {
        public void handle(MouseEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println("mouse released");

            source.setMouseTransparent(false);
            draggablePane.setMouseTransparent(false);
            source.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
            styledRootNode.getChildren().remove(draggablePane);

            e.consume();

            System.out.println("mouse released done");
        }
    });
}
```

I've tried just hardcoding a position update as a test, that also fails to relocate the pane. If anyone has any ideas, even in the slightest, I'd love to give them a try. I've been stuck on this for a few days. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have time to create a full example with the error of your code. So here's one of my own examples, extended with a StackPane, to show you how it works:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Ellipse;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DragExample extends Application {

    Circle circle_R, circle_G, circle_B;
    WrappedInStackPane wrapped;
    double orgSceneX, orgSceneY;
    double orgTranslateX, orgTranslateY;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Create Circles
        circle_R = createCircle( 50, Color.RED, 100, 100);
        circle_G = createCircle( 50, Color.GREEN, 400, 100);
        circle_B = createCircle( 50, Color.BLUE, 700, 100);

        wrapped = new WrappedInStackPane();

        Group root = new Group();
        root.getChildren().addAll(circle_R, circle_G, circle_B, wrapped);

        primaryStage.setResizable(true);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1600, 900));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public Circle createCircle( double radius, Color color, double x, double y) {

        Circle circle;

        circle = new Circle(50.0f, color);
        circle.setCursor(Cursor.MOVE);
        circle.setTranslateX(x);
        circle.setTranslateY(y);
        circle.setOnMousePressed(onMousePressedEventHandler);
        circle.setOnMouseDragged(onMouseDraggedEventHandler);

        return circle;
    }
    EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMousePressedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
            orgSceneX = t.getSceneX();
            orgSceneY = t.getSceneY();
            orgTranslateX = ((Node) (t.getSource())).getTranslateX();
            orgTranslateY = ((Node) (t.getSource())).getTranslateY();
        }
    };

    EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMouseDraggedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
            double offsetX = t.getSceneX() - orgSceneX;
            double offsetY = t.getSceneY() - orgSceneY;
            double newTranslateX = orgTranslateX + offsetX;
            double newTranslateY = orgTranslateY + offsetY;

            ((Node) (t.getSource())).setTranslateX(newTranslateX);
            ((Node) (t.getSource())).setTranslateY(newTranslateY);
        }
    };

    public class WrappedInStackPane extends StackPane {

        public WrappedInStackPane() {

            setStyle("-fx-background-color: orange;");

            Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse(100, 50);
            ellipse.setFill(Color.YELLOW);

            Label label = new Label( "Inside StackPane");

            getChildren().addAll(ellipse, label);

            setOnMousePressed(onMousePressedEventHandler);
            setOnMouseDragged(onMouseDraggedEventHandler);

            relocate(200, 200);

        }
    }
}
```

I suggest you set a background style on your StackPane in order to see if something is off.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, the handling of listeners changes between FX2.2 and FX8.0. Before I was deleting and object from the scene and adding another. In FX2.2 the object won't be garbage collected, but in FX8.0 is appears it is (and when it is, the drag routine freezes). By performing a swap rather than a deletion of the original object when the drag starts, the reference remains and then the original object can be destroyed in the drag completed handler.